# Load the User object on each request in a controller, how to make this object available?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

From what I understand controllers in play are singletons, so I'm not sure how to go about this.

In Rails I could simply load a user in the base_controller, and then in any controller that inherits from the base_controller the user object would be available for me to use.

In play, I'm not sure how this will work.  Basically in each Action in a controller I want the user object to be available for me.

```
def someAction = {
    val name = user.name
    val age = user.age
    Ok("hello")
}
```

Is this possible in play?  I'm' sure it is but I can't seem to figure out way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you'll be able to make it quite as terse as Rails, but using Play's [Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) style you can build up something quite flexible.

We start by creating a trait which knows how to build such a user, and wraps a normal `Action`, allowing the User to be obtained, and passed into the body:

```
trait UserAware {

  def buildUserFromCookie(request:RequestHeader):Option[User] = {

    request.cookies.get("myUserCookie").map { c =>
      // Build up a User object from cookie contents
      // ...
    }
  }

  def cookieNotFound = Results.InternalServerError("Lost your session cookie :-(")

  def UserAction(f: User => Request[AnyContent] => SimpleResult):Action[AnyContent] =
    UserAction[AnyContent](BodyParsers.parse.anyContent)(f)

  def UserAction[T](bodyParser:BodyParser[T])(f: (User) => Request[T] => SimpleResult):Action[T] = {
    Action(bodyParser) { request =>
      buildUserFromCookie(request).fold(cookieNotFound) ({ user =>
        f(user)(request)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I'm going to assume that you have a session cookie that holds sufficient information to be able to recreate a User object. Whatever you need to do within `buildUserFromCookie()` is out of scope here.

I've defined two `UserAction` wrappers, one delegating to the other. The difference is whether you need a special body parser or not. Below you'll see it in use.

The second `UserAction` method is the interesting one - if you supply it with a method that can take a `User` and a `Request`, it will call it for you after creating the user, or bombing out if it can't find the cookie.

Here it is in use:

```
object MyController extends Controller with UserAware {

  def doSomething = UserAction { implicit user => implicit request =>
    Ok(s"The user's name is $user.")
  }

  def doSomethingJsonish = UserAction(parse.json) { implicit user => implicit request =>
    Ok(s"The user's name is $user and their request body is JSON: ${request.body}")
  }
}
```

With the overloaded `UserAction`s, you can still use Play's Body Parsers to get access to a nicely-typed request body, and you've got the freshly-created `User` available as `user`.